# Messages in the cloud - can I force a "re-sync" to the cloud?

Tags: iphone, mac, icloud, messages

I have a deleted conversation in Messages on my iPhone. Since I have set up Messages in the cloud on all my devices, I am seeing that conversation is deleted on my iPad too.

However, as my Mac was booting up, I was able to turn off that setting, so the old messages are still there on the Mac Messages app.

I am almost certain if I turn that cloud setting on again, those old messages are going to be deleted. Is there a way to force a one-way sync from my Mac to iCloud?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  Do you want to recover the conversation you deleted on your other devices?

Comment: Yes, I’d like to recover the conversation (which is only on the Mac) and make it available on my iPhone.

Comment: You can't force a one-way sync.  I think you're correct that connecting back will delete your message. There's many 3rd party applications that can save your Message thread to your Mac.

Comment: I found a way to read the sqlite DB that stores the messages on the Mac [here] (https://spin.atomicobject.com/2020/05/22/search-imessage-sql/). So I was thinking, would I be able to get to my end result by doing this: 1) make a copy of the DB from ~/Library/Messages, 2) re-enable Messages in the cloud and then 3) replace the DB from the copy made?